# Notice: iconv(): Wrong charset, conversion from `MacRoman' to `UTF-16BE'

Tags: magento-2.1, error, log

I am constantly getting this error/Notice on my system logs:

```
Notice: iconv(): Wrong charset, conversion from `MacRoman' to `UTF-16BE' is not allowed  in /data/vhosts/edgars/web/lib/Zend/Pdf/FileParser.php on line 451
```

which is pointing to this function

```
    public function readStringMacRoman($byteCount, $characterSet = '')
    {
        if ($byteCount == 0) {
            return '';
        }
        $bytes = $this->_dataSource->readBytes($byteCount);
        if ($characterSet == 'MacRoman') {
            return $bytes;
        }
        return iconv('MacRoman', $characterSet, $bytes);
    }
```

what could be causing this error I can see it has to do with converting to pdf and that is when encoding happen, and it also have something to do with the languages that `verien library` does not support, so when you printing and sale > order > invoice in the backend using `Thai language or Chinese`

And how to get rid of the error ?